# Calculating the Probability of Consecutive Events in a fixed Population

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I want to find an equation that will calculate the probability of 3 events occurring in a row (consecutive) given a population.

**Example**

1. I have 5 empty slots in a row to place balls __ __ __ __ __
2. Balls are drawn randomly from a bag (80% chance of black, 20% chance of white, each draw is an independent event that does not affect the next draw)
3. 1 possible arrangement after all the balls are drawn is **B, W, W, B, W**
4. What is the probability that after all the empty slots are filled, I will have *AT LEAST* 3 black balls in-a-row? Example would be **W, B, B, B, B**

**Equation Inputs:**

1. Sample/population size = X
2. Probability of drawing back ball = P(B) [which then means P(W) = 1-P(B)]

**Equation Output:**

Probability of having *AT LEAST* 3 black balls in a row anywhere in the population

**Note**

Of course with a small population, I can simply brute force each scenario and sum the probabilities, but the reason I need an equation is because my population size could be 1000

Comment: What is the "population"? The number of slots? The number of colors?

Comment: Number of slots :)